# Raspberry PI 4 + Open media vault + SSD/USB + NAS Server very slow data copy

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-buster

I'm trying to set up NAS server using RasPi 4, Open media vault, 1 TB SSD hardisk(WD). The challenge I'm experiencing is slow data copy rate[3-4 MB/sec] while copying the files from my laptop[Connected to wifi] to RasPI connected to LAN cable.

Tried fixing with usb-storage.quirks [https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=245931], but it still didn't fix my issue.

SSD uses EXT4 file system.

Looking for your help, to address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the bottleneck is you WiFi speed. Unless you have 5GHz WiFi, 3-4 MB/s is a completely reasonable speed for a 54Mbps connection, after you factor in eventual packet loss and protocol overhead.

If you plan to switch to 5GHz WiFi (or already have it), you may want to check [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/121225/33476) to know what data rates you can expect. It won't be exactly your case (Pi connected with Ethernet cable), but whatever is written about the built-in adapter of the Pi applies to laptop WiFi adapters too, to some extent.

Running `sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda` should give you a first estimation of how fast your disk is.

Comment: Currently, Pi connected to a 5GHz wifi, stil getting the same speed.



`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing cached reads:   1542 MB in  2.00 seconds = 771.60 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 350 MB in  3.01 seconds = 116.45 MB/sec`

Comment: @Paramesh Try running `top` during a file transfer: it could be that your server is doing it inefficiently and the transfer is CPU-bound.

Answer (score 0):

For the lowest common denominator, you say you are copying data from a wireless connection to a NAS wired up to the LAN.  In this case, the bottleneck is likely in your Wireless upload speed.  If you connect the laptop to the LAN with a wire, does the copy speed increase?

Some more information on your hardware would help to determine what the problems are ie. Wireless card/driver in the laptop, switch model, RAID configuration of the NAS.

There are probably other factors to consider that I am too smooth brained to talk about in any real way, but that would be my first step in troubleshooting this.

Comment: That's correct, I'm facing slow transfer between laptop and Raspberry pi - NAS server.    Hardware details:

Comment: That's correct, I'm facing slow transfer between laptop and Raspberry pi - NAS server.

Hardware details:

Raspberry PI 4 -> 4 GB RAM 

Western Digital Ultra 1 TB HD 

1 Gigabit LAN 

Macbook pro [laptop]

I havent' figured the RAID. 

Followed this blog setup NAS server [https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-openmediavault/#:~:text=OpenMediaVault%20is%20a%20networked%20attached,a%20variety%20of%20different%20services.].